# Bevel constantly regardless of face size (don't stretch bevel)

Tags: bevel

I want to bevel a rectangular prism, but when I stretch the prism, instead of keeping the same bevel, the bevel stretches as well. How can I get the bevel to stay the same size while the prism is stretched?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Although the answers are the same, inset ≠ bevel.

Comment: True, not exactly the same problem, but basically caused by the same underlying issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Bevel modifier, scale the object and then Apply the transform using CTRL+A -> Scale.